# Remove post from latest posts after a month only with certain tag

Tags: functions, post-meta, query-posts

I was wondering if there is a way to modify the wordpress loop to check posts with a certain tag and if they have that tag and are 1 month old not display them in the latest posts on the homepage?

Edit: Something like

```
function removeFromLoop(){
  if(post_age >= "31" && tag == "sometag"){
    query->dont;
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use a **tax_query** to filter the post by custom taxonomy. or wp_query provide the filter called **tag**

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with hundreds of plugins, but I'm happy that someone wants to make it with code.

So that you want is actually not to hidden something but to just take the posts **after the one month ago date**.

```
$onemonth_before = date( 'Y-m-d',strtotime('-1 month') );
$args = array(
    //if you have custom post type 
    'post_type' => 'your-post-type',
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tag' => 'sometag',
    'date_query' => array(
        'after' => $onemonth_before,
        'inclusive' => true,
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This maybe needs some changes to work in you case.

Some more info about the powerful **date_query** can be found in the 
[codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters)

Comment: Is there a way to do some conditional operators in this array? Because I want posts older then a month that don't have tag X but when tag X is present they must be the last month only. I don't want to keep adding plugins to the site when I could be learning how to code it properly.